# how fix props.match undefined

Tags: reactjs

this is my Editstudent.js

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const stud_id = this.props.match; 
    console.log(stud_id);
}
```

this is my App.js

```
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Student/>} />
    <Route path="/add-student" element={<Addstudent/>} />
    <Route path="/edit-student/:id" element={<Editstudent/>} />
  </Routes>
```

but i got error, it said undefined
what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you should wrap `Editstudent.js` in `withRouter`

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class EditStudent extends React.Component {
   async componentDidMount() {
     const stud_id = this.props.match; 
     console.log(stud_id);
   }
}

export default withRouter(EditStudent);
```

You can check [this document](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) for a better understanding

---

If you use `react-router-dom` v6 which does not support class-based components, you can have HOC ([higher-order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)) with [react router hooks](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usematch) (`useMatch`, `useParams`, etc.) like below

```
import { useMatch } from "react-router-dom";

//HOC like this
function withMatch(Component) {
  return props => <Component {...props} match={useMatch()} />;
}

class EditStudent extends React.Component {
   async componentDidMount() {
     const stud_id = this.props.match; 
     console.log(stud_id);
   }
}

//use `withMatch` as a wrapper
export default withMatch(EditStudent);
```

Or you can convert your component to function-based components and then use hooks directly

```
import { useMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const EditStudent = () =>  {
   const match = useMatch();
   useEffect(() => {
     const stud_id = match; 
     console.log(stud_id);
   }, []) //similar to `componentDidMount`

   return <div></div> //similar to `render()`
}

export default EditStudent;
```

Comment: I Install latest version react-router v6 and im already used react-router-dom v6, so it cant solve the problem

Comment: @MindMon I modified my answer with latest hooks usage, you can check it out :D